# Chef Creating dynamic Json File

Tags: json, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I got a problem in generate a json file using a template inside a chef template.

I need to generate a json file like below, called plugin.json:

```
{
  "agents": [
    {
      "name"    : "sqlhost",
      "host"    : "localhost",
      "metrics" : "status,newrelic",
      "user"    : "root",
      "passwd"  : "mysecret"
    }
  ]
}
```

This file will be used by the Newrelic plugin

Template File plugin.json.erb:

```
<%= Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty(@name) %>
```

I've created a recipe like this one:
mysql-plugin.rb

```
# Default Variables
newrelic = decrypt_databag('newrelic')
node.default['newrelic_npi']['license_key'] = newrelic['license_key']
plugin = 'com.newrelic.plugins.mysql.instance'
plugin_json_path = "/opt/newrelic-npi/plugins/com.newrelic.plugins.mysql.instance/newrelic_mysql_plugin-2.0.0/config/plugin.json" 
node.default['newrelic_npi']['name'] = "localhost1"

  execute 'fetch' do
    cwd node['newrelic_npi']['install_path']
    user node['newrelic_npi']['user']
    command "./npi fetch #{plugin} -y"
    not_if do
      ::File.exist? "#{node['newrelic_npi']['install_path']}/plugins/#{plugin}"
    end
  end

  execute 'prepare' do
    cwd node['newrelic_npi']['install_path']
    user node['newrelic_npi']['user']
    command "./npi prepare #{plugin}"
  end


 template "#{plugin_json_path}" do
    source 'plugin.json.erb'
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    mode "0644"
    variables  :name => node['newrelic_npi']['name']
    action :create
end

  execute 'add-service' do
    cwd node['newrelic_npi']['install_path']
    user node['newrelic_npi']['user']
    command "sudo ./npi add-service #{plugin} --start" # needs root privileges
    not_if do
      ::File.exist? "/etc/init.d/newrelic_plugin_#{plugin}"
    end
  end
```

At the Template block what should I do to make a Json file like plugin.json?

```
template "#{plugin_json_path}" do
        source 'plugin.json.erb'
        owner "root"
        group "root"
        mode "0644"
        variables  :name => node['newrelic_npi']['name']
        action :create
    end
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have any stack trace / error output? I see a few potential issues, but you did not show what exact problem is.

Comment: Hi @SzymonSzypulski, there is no problem or erro, I just wanna to create a Dynamic Json File from a template to be  like showed like the Json file at the top of the question.

Comment: @coderanger do you get any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First. You should be setting any default **node** variables inside `default.rb` in your attributes folder. Like this:

```
default['newrelic_npi']['license_key'] = newrelic['license_key']
default['newrelic_npi']['name'] = "localhost1"
```

Node attributes are reset before compilation and will pull from that file as well as Ohai. Setting node attributes inside the recipe means they aren't going to be available for your template (you should review this [Chef Client Overview](https://docs.chef.io/chef_client_overview.html)).

Next, if you just need to set the hostname or another specific portion of the template file you can do this inside your `erb` file:

```
{
  "agents": [
    {
      "name"    : "sqlhost",
      "host"    : "<%= @name %>",
      "metrics" : "status,newrelic",
      "user"    : "root",
      "passwd"  : "mysecret"
    }
  ]
}
```

Your current erb file is trying to convert `@name` (which you try to set to `localhost1`) to json, not set the whole file like your example.

Comment: That do the trick, it so simple.
default['newrelic_npi']['license_key'] = newrelic['license_key']
default['newrelic_npi']['name'] = "localhost1"
Ok it was just to describe the cookbook, now I'm managing to correct the recipe.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a correct plugin.json:

```
{
  "agents": [
    {
      "name"    : <%= Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty(@name) %>,
      "host"    : <%= Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty(@host) %>,
      "metrics" : <%= Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty(@metrics) %>,
      "user"    : <%= Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty(@user) %>,
      "passwd"  : <%= Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty(@passwd) %>
    }
  ]
}
```

At the template Block I did like:

```
template node['newrelic_npi']['plugin_json_path'] do
    source 'plugin.json.erb'
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0644'
    variables(
      :name => node['newrelic_npi']['name'],
      :host => node['newrelic_npi']['host'],
      :metrics => node['newrelic_npi']['metrics'],
      :user => node['newrelic_npi']['user'],
      :passwd => node['newrelic_npi']['myql_admin_password']
)
    action :create
end
```